# Spring Boot with JPA and H2 with auto increment id column: NULL not allowed for column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I'm trying to follow an example project in *Spring Security in Action* but use H2 rather than MySQL and I'm struggling to find the right combination of configurations to allow things to work properly.

My simple entity, which is just a simple object with a primary key. I the "id" column to behave like an auto-incremented primary key in that the DB should generate it rather than the application.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Workout {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String user;
    private LocalDateTime start;
    private LocalDateTime end;
    private int difficulty;
}
```

My repository (nothing special):

```java
@Repository
public interface WorkoutRepository extends JpaRepository<Workout, Integer> {
}
```

Relevant parts of the controller, which just receives a Workout object with no id specified and saves it to the DB:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/workout")
public class WorkoutController {
    
    private final WorkoutRepository workoutRepository;

    public WorkoutController(WorkoutRepository  workoutRepository) {
        this.workoutRepository= workoutRepository;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/")
    public Workout add(@RequestBody Workout workout) {
        return workoutRepository.save(workout);
    }
    
}
```

And my `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/fitnessapp;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
# using this because I have a column called "user" which is a reserved word
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

When I run this, the application starts up and I can check the H2 console and see that the table was created correctly. But when I submit a request to save a new entity I get an internal server error.

Logs show that the resulting SQL tries to set the "id" column to NULL, which causes an SQL error:

```
Hibernate: insert into "workout" ("id", "difficulty", "end", "start", "user") values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-02-08 16:04:48.427  WARN 22656 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23502, SQLState: 23502
2023-02-08 16:04:48.427 ERROR 22656 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : NULL not allowed for column "id"; SQL statement:
insert into "workout" ("id", "difficulty", "end", "start", "user") values (null, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23502-200]
```

So even though JPA is defining the schema for the entity, it doesn't seem to know how to insert rows into the table.

I've tried many different combinations of `GenerationType` strategy, creating the table schema myself with a `schema.sql` file (though I'd rather not resort to this as JPA should be able to do it for me), and various hibernate properties. Nothing seems to work.

Versions:

- Spring Boot parent: 2.3.0.RELEASE
- Spring Data JPA: 2.3.0.RELEASE
- H2: 1.4.200

Comment: Try to change your id field type from primitive int to Integer and add Lomboks @NoArgsConstructor at the class level. Also you could try delete the H2 file and re-create it

Comment: Changing to Integer seems to have done the trick, though I have no idea why. The logs still show that the resulting SQL is trying to set the "id" column to NULL, but now it doesn't throw an error. This is not a change due to deleting the h2 file because I've been doing that every time I've been making a change just to make sure it wasn't some old schema hanging around causing a problem.

Comment: @meridbt if you put your comment as an answer I will accept it